# Running nano WinSSHD and Putty

Tags: windows, putty, nano

I have following setup;

- Windows 7 running WinSSHD
- GitBash (WinSSHD launches this as console when connected)
- Nano 2.2.6 WIN32 version
- Remote Windows with Putty connected via ssh to above server

Everything else works just fine; console, VIM, git, etc. But when I start my favourite editor nano, the keyboard is not working correctly; Arrow keys respond with `[ unknown command ]`, <kbd>Alt</kbd> (or <kbd>AltGr</kbd>) is completely ignored, as in Finnish keyboard the {[]} are coming from <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+7890, so it is tricky to compose code.

I can move around with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>,<kbd>N</kbd>,<kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>B</kbd> -keys

Nano works fine when started from local cmd-prompt or from gitbash-shell.

Is there any way to fix this keyboard issue with my configuration?